# Code is buggy on comparing strings

Tags: php

The issue i'm having, is when I edit the string "dbPassword", my script will run fine as in notice that the 2 string dont match. For example if I remove the letter "c"

```
d

array(1) { ["c"]=> int(6) } not matching.. 
123bdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc
123bcdbddbcabcccbdaabba
```

but when I do the same thing to the `$anPassword` string, it gives me an OK message basically.
Instead though, it only causes the issue with 
The blank space is where I took out a letter. (The letter B)

```
$anPassword = "123bdcbad cabcbcadcbadbc"; //Removed 1 letter
$dbPassword = "123bdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc"; //Unchanged / original string
```

and it still gives me..

Should be matching... Theoredically...
123bdcbadcabcbcadcbadbc
123abadabccbbbddcbacdcbc

Basically, why is  my code bugging out and returning that it's matchng when it obviously isnt. and why is only some characters causing it.

```
$anPassword = "123bdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc"; //User encrypted password on form submission
$dbPassword = "123bdcbadbcabcbcadcbadbc"; //Database encrypted password.

$begChars1[0] = substr($anPassword, 0, 3);
$begChars1[1] = substr($anPassword, 3);

$begChars2[0] = substr($dbPassword, 0, 3);
$begChars2[1] = substr($dbPassword, 3);
$begChars2[2] = str_shuffle($begChars2[1]);

$compData1 = array_count_values(str_split($begChars1[1]));
$compData2 = array_count_values(str_split($begChars2[2]));
$result = array_diff($compData1, $compData2);

if($begChars1[0] != $begChars2[0]) {
    echo "not matching...";

}

if($result == null) {
    echo "Should be matching... Theoredically...";
} else {
    echo "not matching.. " . var_dump($result);
}

echo "<br />" . $begChars1[0] . $begChars1[1] . "<br />" . $begChars2[0] . $begChars2[2];
```

Comment: This is confusing, what are you trying to accomplish exactly ?

Comment: `array_diff` will never return `null`, it always returns an array. If the two arrays are the same, it returns an empty array, not `null`.

Comment: @Barmar: `var_dump(array() == null);` but yes `!$result` or something is probably better.

Comment: I'd use `if (empty($result))`

Comment: I got it, thanks guys. And all I'm doing with this is practicing PHP, I'm not trying to actually store a password. I was just trying to see how I can compare 2 strings by counting the characters, and assuming they're correct. But I was trying to use it with a database, and thought the best idea was make a very simplistic user system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what it is you're trying to accomplish but here's what I'm seeing.

Most of your confusion stems from what appears to be this line.

```
$result = array_diff($compData1, $compData2);
```

You're thinking this is going to return all differences about the two arrays. What this actually does is returns the values in array1 that are not present in array2.

Your arrays both look like this before the comparison.

```
array (size=4)
  'b' => int 7
  'd' => int 4
  'c' => int 6
  'a' => int 4

array (size=4)
  'a' => int 4
  'c' => int 6
  'd' => int 4
  'b' => int 7
```

Both strings contain the same amount of each character, youre just shuffling them for some reason. array_diff is understandably going to return nothing because theres really nothing different about the arrays sans the order of the elements.

If you dropped an 'x' in the second string, you'd see something in `$result`.

You could save yourself a lot of trouble by not storing passwords via whatever crazy method you're trying to invent. [Hash them like everyone else instead.](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: I'm not storing them with this 'crazy' method haha. I'm just honestly trying to practice PHP. This isn't going to be apart of something. Anyways, thank you. I understand now.

Comment: :) you'd be surprised at the crazy things people try to do. however, kudos on investigating things on your own and asking when you dont understand. a lot of people panic at the first thing that doesnt make perfect sense

Comment: So at this point I plan on counting how many times a letter/number/symbol appears in each string. and then compare each string to how many times a letter appears, if the numbers match up, I would assume the 2 strings match, even if 1 of them is shuffled. Or am I still looking at it wrong? 

something like $aChar1 = substr_count($string1, "a"); $aChar2 = substr_count($string2, "a"); and compare the number they return to one another.

Comment: That would only serve to prove that they both contain the same number of specific letters. Using this, "Pantera" would == "Panera". String matching is an already-solved issue. Why recreate the wheel?

Comment: That's what I was trying to do (not reinvent the wheel on a practical level, just messing around.) But I think I got it solved, thanks again for your help.